# MySql Workbench not responding on creating schema

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

when i create a new schema on mysql workbench, it is freezing and not responding. Also my computer is not responding. I cannot do anything even mouse pointer does not move. Here is the environment infos:

OS: Ubuntu 17
Mysql Workbench: 6.3.9
 innodb_version: 5.7.20
protocol_version: 10
slave_type_conversions
tls_version: TLSv1,TLSv1.1
version: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 
version_comment: (Ubuntu)
version_compile_machine: x86_64
version_compile_os: Linux

Comment: After i restart the notebook, i see that schema is created but when trying to execute a select query it is same. Not responding..

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, Ubuntu is accessing the hard drive rapidly. The led blinks every time when the OS accesses the hard drive.

Not sure if this is the case but it seems like you have a really slow drive. If that is the case then this will work

Just boot into Ubuntu and wait a few minutes till the LED stops blinking. Then do what ever you want.

Be patient. Not sure if this will work though

Comment: It seems like you're just guessing at what his actual issue is, you should probably ask for clarification in a comment on his post instead.

Comment: I dont think it is a problem of hard disk drive. I use external HDD, but also a bit time ago i had this problem on notebook HDD.